# How to change background-position of a :after element when user hovers an anchor

Tags: css, pseudo-class

I have an anchor and I'm using a pseudo class `:after` for icons images.
I want to change background position of `:after` when user hovers the element.

I know I can do it using javascript, but I'm trying to figure out a CSS solution, I don't even know if it's possible.

html:

```
<a href="" class="foo">
```

I've tried to do something like this, but obviously it didn't work:
css:

```
.foo{background:top;}
.foo:hover .foo:after{background-position:bottom;}
```

Some help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change your selector:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/hgam4w7y/1/)**

```
.foo::after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    background:url('http://placekitten.com/g/200/300');
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    transition: all .3s;
}
.foo:hover::after { /* this part */
    background-position:50%;
    transition: all .3s;
}
```

Comment: It is recommended to use `::` for pseudo-elements, eg `::after`, and `:` for pseudo-classes, eg `:hover`. Therefore, `.foo:hover::after` would be nicer ;) although most browsers have no problems with `:after`.

Comment: @Terry Thanks, I didn't know that, [checked with the w3c](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-elements/:after) it looks like you're right. Learn something new everyday...